# how to let fabric use ssh master ControlMaster config?

Tags: python, linux, ssh, fabric, openssh

I follow this article describes changes the ssh configuration.

http://www.anchor.com.au/blog/2010/02/ssh-controlmaster-the-good-the-bad-the-ugly/

I can quickly connect to my server when use ssh myserver,
But the fabric does not use these config, it is still very slow when connection.

after I add the following code, problem still not solved。

```
env.use_ssh_config=True 
env.ssh_config_path='/etc/ssh/ssh_config'
```